# How can I make the below change query dynamic for each table, I have my id column as common?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DECLARE @currentVersion bigint = (SELECT TOP 1 LastVersion FROM VersionTracking WHERE TableName='Test1')
    DECLARE @newVersion bigint = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()
 
    SELECT
        CT.EmployeeID, 
        Test1.Name, 
        Test1.Position,
        CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION, 
        CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS,
        CT.SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT
    FROM 
        Test1
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
        CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbo.Test1, @currentVersion) CT ON Test1.EmployeeID = CT.EmployeeID
 
    UPDATE VersionTracking 
    SET LastVersion = @newVersion 
    WHERE TableName = 'Test1'

    COMMIT
```

How to make the above query dynamic in case of multiple tables? So that we can use this for each of the table with SSIS packages or ADF

Comment: dynamic sql maybe?

Comment: Do you want to dynamically replace the table name(dbo.Test1)？